# improper integrals (comparison theorem)

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

In my assignment I have to evaluate the (improper) integral, by means of the "comparison theorem". And note whether the function is divergent or convergent. $$\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{x}{x^3 + 1}dx$$

The comparison theorem basically says

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions with $f(x) \geq  (x)$ for $x \geq a$. Then:
>   A) if $\int^\infty_af(x)dx$ is convergent then $\int^\infty_ag(x)dx$ is convergent
>   B) if $\int^\infty_ag(x)dx$ is divergent then $\int^\infty_af(x)dx$ is divergent

So in other words: to prove if a given integral is convergent you find a function whose integral is larger than the given integral (within the boundaries). And to prove divergence you find a "divergent integral" whose function is always smaller than the function is question.

Now how should I go with this? Is there any trick to the above? Can I "see" (without calculator/automatic plotting) if an integral will be divergent or convergent (so to reduce time)?

Answer (score 2):

I think $$\int_0^\infty 1/x^2$$ diverges because ,in $[0,1]$ given integral diverges.
What we have to do is split the given integral like this.
$$\int_0^\infty \frac {x}{x^3+1}=
\int_0^1 \frac {x}{x^3+1}  + \int_1^\infty \frac {x}{x^3+1}$$
Definitely second integral converges.
Taking first integral
We have $$x\leq x^4$$ for $x\in [0,1]$
So given function $$\frac {x}{x^3+1} \leq \frac {x^4}{x^3+1} \leq \frac {x^4}{x^3} = x$$
Since $g(x)=x$ is convegent in $[0,1]$, first integral convergent 
Hence given integral converges

Answer (score 1):

You can "see" the convergence of the integral by noting that assimptotically $\frac{x}{x^3+1}\sim \frac{1}{x^2}$. As $\int_a^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}dx$ converges when $a>0$, so does $\int_a^{\infty}\frac{x}{x^3+1}dx$. This argument can be made precise by using the fact that for $x>1$, $\frac{x}{x^3+1}=\frac{1}{x^2+\frac{1}{x}}<\frac{1}{x^2}$, and applying the comparison theorem you stated.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\frac { x }{ { x }^{ 3 }+1 } <\frac { x }{ { x }^{ 3 } } =\frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 2 } }$$ for $x>0$

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}dx$ diverges so probably the hints above are not good since you want to verify the convergence of
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^3+1}dx.$$
I'm not sure whether it is the best evaluation but e.g.
since
$x^3+1 = (x+1)(x^2-x+1)$
we have $\frac{x}{x^3+1} < \frac{x+1}{x^3+1} = \frac{1}{x^2-x+1}$

and we can show that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2-x+1}dx = \frac{4\sqrt{3}\pi}{9}$ so your integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{x^3+1}$ converges. Although, there might be a better evaluation which gives you ` a better' function $g(x) > \frac{x}{x^3+1}$ whose integral is trivial to solve.

Comment: $int^\infty_0(1/x^p)dx$ converges if p > 1....

Comment: $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} dx = \left[-\frac{1}{x}\right]_{0}^{\infty} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} = \infty$

Comment: If you don't believe above calculations maybe you will believe the computer http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D+1%2F%28x%5E2%29dx $\sum \frac{1}{n^p}$ converges if $p>1$ it is different with the integrals.

Comment: But how does the integrand behave near the origin?  more like $x$.  The integral converges.

Comment: $\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}dx = n$ it converges if $n > 0$. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: The integrand is $x/(1+x^3)$.  Near $x=0$, the denominator is approximately $1$, so the integrand behaves as $x/1=x$ there.  As $x\to\infty$, on the other hand, the integrand behaves as $1/x^2$, which has antiderivative, as you point out $-1/x$, which vanishes at that limit.  You do not use this antiderivative at the $x=0$ limit, as the integrand does not behave like that there.  In fact, the integral has value $2 \pi/(3 \sqrt{3})$, which is very easy to show.

Comment: Sure, I agree with that. I thought that the main task of this excercise was to show that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^3+1}dx$ converges by finding the function $g$ such that $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for $x\geq 0$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)dx < \infty$.