# How to evaluate improper integral of odd function?

Tags: complex-analysis

I recently was solving $\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x}{x^3+1}dx$. I wrote x as z to do contour integration and did the indentation for the pole at real axis but I don't know what to do with this odd function? How should I go further, write the z in terms of $\theta$ by euler formula? This is not homework question,I started learning complex analysis recently so I want to know the concepts used for such questions.

Comment: Do you want the answer to be done by only complex analysis methods?

Comment: yes it was in the exercise of complex analysis chapter so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [improper integrals (comparison theorem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534461/improper-integrals-comparison-theorem)

Comment: Oddness of the integrand does'nt matter here.

Comment: The duplicate checks only the convergence, but did not find the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the function $z\mapsto z^3 + 1$ is invariant under rotation by $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, it will be useful to start with the contour integral $$\oint_{\Gamma(R)} \frac{z}{z^3 + 1}\, dz$$ where $\Gamma(R)$ is the positively oriented sector of radius $R$ in the first and second quadrants subtended by angle $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. Namely, $\Gamma(R) = [0,R] \cup \gamma_R \cup L_R$ where $\gamma_R$ is the arc of radius $R$ and $L_R$ is the line segment from $Re^{2\pi i/3}$ to $0$. For large enough $R$ the sector contains the simple pole at $z = e^{i\pi/3}$. By the residue theorem the contour integral is $2\pi i$ times the residue of $\frac{z}{z^3 + 1}$ at $z = e^{\pi i/3}$, which evaluates to $$2\pi i \frac{e^{\pi i/3}}{3(e^{\pi i/3})^2} = \frac{2\pi i}{3 e^{\pi i/3}}$$ The integrand is $O(R^{-2})$ as $R\to \infty$ so by the ML-inequality its integral over the arc $\gamma_R$ is $O(R^{-1})$ as $R\to \infty$. Now using parametrization $z = xe^{2\pi i /3}$, $0 \le x \le R$, we write $$\int_{L_R} \frac{z}{z^3 + 1}\, dz = -\int_0^R \frac{xe^{2\pi i/3}}{x^3 + 1}\, e^{2\pi i/3}\, dx = -e^{4\pi i/3}\int_0^R \frac{x}{x^3 + 1}\, dx$$ Therefore $$\frac{2\pi i}{3e^{\pi i/3}} = (1 - e^{4\pi i/3})\int_0^R \frac{x}{x^3 + 1}\, dx + O(R^{-1})\quad \text{as $R\to \infty$}$$From this we deduce $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{x^3 + 1}\, dx = \frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: How to choose contour? I have done most questions where we simply choose semicircle in upper half as contour, what factors affect our choice of contour? also is this answer related to branch cut as we do similar thing for multivalued functions

Comment: @Piyushgalav the integrand has no branch points so there are no branch cuts needed to work the problem. As for picking the contour, look back at my first statement in the answer. With more practice you'll get a better feel for choosing useful contours.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{xdx}{1+x^3}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{-1}{3(1+x)}+\frac{(1+x)}{3(x^2-x+1)}\right)dx.$$
$$\implies I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{-1}{3(1+x)}+\frac{(2x-1)/2+3/2}{3(x^2-x+1)}\right)dx.$$
$$\implies I=\left .\left[\frac{-1}{3}\ln(1+x)+\frac{1}{6} \ln (x^2-x+1)\right]\right|_{0}^{\infty}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x-1/2)^2+3/4}$$
$$\implies I=\left .\left[\frac{1}{3}\ln\frac{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}{1+x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \tan^{-1}[(2x-1)/\sqrt{3}] \right] \right  |_{0}^{\infty}$$
$$\implies I=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}.$$
As $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\ln\frac{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}{1+x}=0$$

Comment: In the thrid line, the $\log$'s should be evaluated at the limit points.

Comment: OK, now I have insered some more characters. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume $I=\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{x^3+1}dx$. Now we will make a substitution which is $x=\frac{1}{t}$ & $dx=\frac{-dt}{t^2}$.

So, now $I=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{t^3+1}dt$. Since limits are same for both integrals, we can add both integrals.

Now, $2I=\int_0^\infty\frac{x+1}{x^3+1}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^2-x+1}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}}dx=[\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}tan^{-1}(\frac{(x-\frac{1}{2})}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}})]_0^\infty=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}(\frac{\pi}{2}-(-\frac{\pi}{6}))$

So, $2I=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}(\frac{4\pi}{6})$ which equates to $I=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$

Hope it helps!